# Saga unit test deepEqual returns false anyway

Tags: unit-testing, redux-saga

I am pretty much new with Redux-saga and working on unit test. API call function unit test code returns false even if it looks identical. What am I missing?

[Actions]

```
export const actions = {
  readUsers: {
    read: (data) => util.createAction('READ_USER', data),
    request: () => util.createAction('READ_REQUEST'),
    success: (data: any) => util.createAction('READ_SUCCESS', data),
    failure: (error: any) => util.createAction('READ_FAILURE', error)
  }
};
```

[Generator function]

```
export function* fetchUsers(action) {
  yield put(actions.readUsers.request());
  try {
    let data = {id: action.payload.id, option: action.payload.option};
    let response = yield call(API().getUsers, data);
    if (response) {
      yield put(actions.readUsers.success(response.users));
    } else {
      yield put(actions.readUsers.failure(response.error));
    }
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(actions.readUsers.failure(error));
  }
};
```

[Unit test]

```
const id = 'user-id';
const option = {};
const result = {users: []};
const action = {payload : {id, option}};
describe('user-saga', () => {
  describe('fetchUsers', () => {
    const generator = fetchUsers(action);
    it('should return actions.readUsers.request()', () => {
      assert.deepEqual(generator.next().value, put(actions.readUsers.request()));
    }); // PASS

    it('should return the Api.getUsers call', () => {
      assert.equal(generator.next(result).value, call(Api().getUsers, action.payload));
    }); // FAIL

    it('should return actions.readUsers.success()', () => {
      assert.deepEqual(generator.next(result).value, put(actions.readUsers.success(result)));
    }); // FAIL

    it('should be finished', () => {
      assert.deepEqual(generator.next().done, true);
    }); // PASS
  })
});
```

[Test output]

First test passed.

Second test failed with this error message

```
 AssertionError: { '@@redux-saga/IO': true,
    CALL: { context: null, fn: [Function: getUsers], args: [ [Object] ] } } deepEqual { '@@redux-saga/IO': true,
    CALL: { context: null, fn: [Function: getUsers], args: [ [Object] ] } }
```

Third test failed with this error message

```
AssertionError: undefined deepEqual { '@@redux-saga/IO': true,
 PUT: { channel: null,
       action: { type: 'READ_SUCCESS', users: undefined } } }
```

Comment: What is `Api()` or `API()`? Does this function always return new functions like `getUsers`?

Comment: Yury Tarabanko Yes it is a function returns new functions.

Comment: Functions are not comparable unless by ref. `const a = () => true; const b = () => true; console.log(a === b) // false` so `deepEqual` returns false. The third test is failing because you need to compare it with `put(actions.readUsers.success(result.**users**))`